# Sci-Fi novel based on a role playing game about a postwar scenario

Tags: story-identification, books

I began to read this book in the 90s, then lost it. Unfortunately I cannot remember the title, only that it was based on a role playing game from that time. It's about a postwar scenario.

Special bombs were thrown on some parts of the land, where all memory was erased. There was an outpost where specialists and workers of all kind gathered. A storm was coming from the desert, a side effect of the bombing with the memory killing bombs.

Comment: So, if you say "post-war RPG" I think *Twilight: 2000* and (maybe) *Gamma World*, but neither of those (IIRC) ever had tie-in novels.  OTOH, for an RPG system with tie-in novels, I'm thinking *Shadowrun*, but I don't think it would really count as "post-war."  *Shadowrun* might fight better with a memory-wiping bomb, though, the concept is too fantastic for *T:2k*.  Maybe *Rifts*?  (Though I've never played it.)

Comment: OTOH and Rifts sounds good. Thanks, I need to research that. But Shadowrun is pure fantasy and not a typical science fiction / postwar thing. Although I enjoyed playing Shadowrun a lot during my youth. The book I search was a novel with dense atmosphere, explaining a lot about the postwar.